# Lazy Module Chunk.js gets loaded all together

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-template

I have optimize my code to lazy module my home page gets loaded quickly but after login that is moving to dashboard page all the lazy module chunk files are getting loaded. How to optimize that ?? Does any one has idea how to avoid all the chunk files to get load at once. Even I fell API call to rest services are responding slow is this behavior is due to lazy module feature ?? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable lazy loading, you can also specify when you want the application to load the chunks. This is done by setting the **preloadingStrategy** parameter in the options object that you may pass to the router in addition to the routes you're registering. Here's how it looks like:

```
imports: [
  ...
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
    { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
],
```

You can specify one of two default strategies - **NoPreloading** or **PreloadAllModules** - or you can write your own. This page has some more examples:
https://alligator.io/angular/preloading/

Comment: Great One. It worked and saved the lot of time. Thanks !! @Artem Zakharov.